# opening files .arc

Tags: windows-7, pdf, archiving, extract

I need to open a folder with the extension of .arc .
I've already extracting the file with 7zip and also have tried it using IZArc extractor.But it seems to give me the output of many file (unknown type) that cannot be open by with any file programs.When I try to open it with notepad,it just show some alphanumeric string.The example are as below :

**File 1** :*H4sIAAAAAAAAAKx7aZOq2tLm94qo/7BBBXFAHBlVRgVUcAJUVEQUxYFJfePt/tC/valz7r7n9I3bb3dEd1UsFNZAZq7MJ59ce1dhKg6qdbT1/VX/hf2KjrfvL4b5/qoJ6dl9R+mvop663uNMBtzi1/wcR+n79WtxTv8j8M4v5Pe4IApF933+VRSpBoaRGN5oNpr1Zqv+M2ISnf63nVn3NI1OH+/8zzf9ygT6dUqD*

**.
.
File 81:** */zinP7OXwTt7Vqw3Wo0xL8gS9vPT7HTaeAeNT/7PEO7zvv4l6W8ps55e7/vrHJ7+UKr9l3a18Tm8vK+/OtmjeTZ/EDze2fvtGrcQFIVoi2cvOp1/1QaPTOw/b3Z/LvZ6Z9o+v7+G7udg9XovUim2RoVNum8NqRkiHmmFzWPWAG0FrrM9Y+szPjodu2THBclHFeTTFBpCJLA8ambZH0AgOXUyKSkWAKMzgjql0shjAP1F8ccufbverZpWS3IffsHg6rD64PfhSbg/FeGS*

That .arc files supposed to be a pdf file.I know this because the sender itself telling me that way.

Can anyone show me the way to open this file?Thanks.

p/s: sorry for my bad English. Feel free to edit this question if anyone can make it more understandable .

Comment: yup..100%.it seems like it has been encoded inside

Comment: I just created a testfile (arc a test.arc my_testfile.txt) and the resulting test.arc contains a lot of NON-alphanumeric information. Which seems to suggest that the file you have is not in arc format. (My output looks like this:  `^Z^Htestfile.txt^@[^D^@^@~KA| ¾Cþ'^G^@^@^Leì¼aS~GN~Z7nZÈp1ca~L/3^T^D^\Xð`B2aè`)

Comment: yes..actually the things is what you've done is just reading the compressing file/folder is it?.But like as I have mention above,what I want is the output after we extracting the .arc folder.That is, it should show me a pdf file after extracting the folder.Btw,The file 1 until file 81 that I have mention above is the file INSIDE the folder after extracting.

Comment: `arc z test.arc` gives me the contents of the archive (when used on a known working archive). However this seems to become a discussion, which might be better in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6703/arc-files

Comment: i want to discuss inside the links given but I'm unable to so as I do not have the sufficient reputation to chat

Comment: For your information,its 81 files for single pdf.I don't know why its splitting until 81 files when extracting the .arc folder

Comment: Could it be that the PDF got arc'ed and then split into separate smaller files? What happens it you concatenate all files? (You can do that from a cmd prompt with `copy /b file1 file2 file3 ... file81 finalfile`.)

Comment: so i need to put into one command for all that file?whoa..it will take a while

Comment: Depends. I do not really know windows shells. Might be doable with powershell since it has many unix shell like features. (and in unix using bash it would just be this:  for a in `seq 1 81`; do cat file$a >> finalfile; done

Comment: for %f in (*) do type “%f” >> myfile
this is the command I put inside the bash.It works well but it seems the output is unreadeable by pdf viewer.but when I open in notepad the value inside are all the strings inside of each file from 1 until 81.so what should I do know?any thought

Comment: On a side note: Do the files contain confidential data? Or can you link to them?

Comment: sorry..although i want to do that i cannot disclose this as it contain private data of the client.Seems like a dead end to me.

Comment: You win some, you loose some. Might be best to ask the client to resent the file in another format. (even though solving what went wrong would be an interesting puzzle, it is probably not the best business solution)

Comment: agreed..I'm also interested to solve this issue.but I do not have time to do this as I have another priority that need to be done.The client cannot change the format because the file is generated by software application.Anyway,for now I try to goggling around to see if I can manage to do something about this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a possibility to contact the vendor of the software on the .arc type used.
According to wikipedia there are several different forms of arc which are incompatible with oneother.